# "Debug Assertion Failed" while reading a txt file

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to create a C++ program that reads a text file with the following contents:

```
ITEMS 8
ABERDEEN    430082  3.2  5.0
GLASGOW     629501  2.0  1.5
PAISLEY     74170   1.0  1.0
MOTHERWELL  30311   3.0  1.0
EDINBURGH   430082  5.0  1.3
FALKIRK     32379   3.1  1.2
LINLTHGOW   13370   3.0  1.5
DUNDEE      154674  3.2  3.1
```

My Program crashes with the following error:

[image]

The program reads some of the contents of the file until a certain point:
[image]

One interesting thing that I noticed is that my X and Y coordinates of each town are supposed to be both doubles and when I read the file some of the X/Ys are ints or doubles (No idea how that is happening). I am storing each of the towns as a Town object in an area of towns like that:
This is my read from file method:

```
bool TownReader::readDatafile(char *datafile)
{
    ostringstream errorString;

    ifstream inDatastream(datafile, ios::in);

    if (!inDatastream)
    {       
        errorString << "Can't open file " << datafile << " for reading.";
        MessageBoxA(NULL, errorString.str().c_str(), "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return false;
    }

    cout << "Reading from file: " << datafile << endl; 

    readUntil(&inDatastream, "ITEMS");
    //Read the number of towns...
    inDatastream >> numTowns;
    //reserve the nesessery memory...
    TownPtr = new Town[ numTowns ];

    cout << "Number of towns: " << numTowns << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < numTowns; ++i)
    {
        Town newTown;
        char townName[] = "";
        double townX = 0.0;
        double townY = 0.0;
        int townPopulation = 0;
        inDatastream >> townName >> townPopulation >> townX >> townY;
        cout << "Town name: " << townName << endl;
        cout << "Town pop: " << townPopulation << endl;
        cout << "Town X: " << townX << endl;
        cout << "Town Y: " << townY << endl;

        newTown.setName(townName);
        newTown.setPopulation(townPopulation);
        newTown.setX(townX);
        newTown.setY(townX);

        TownPtr[i] = newTown;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This method is part if the following class: TownReader. Here is the header of the class:

```
class TownReader
{
private:
    Town *TownPtr;
    int numTowns;

public:
    TownReader(void);
    bool readDatafile(char *filename);
    bool writeDatafile(char *filename);

    bool readUntil(std::ifstream *inStream, char *target);


    Town *getTowns(void);
    int getNumTowns(void);

    bool writeBlankRecords(char *datafile, int num);
    bool writeTownsBinary(char *datafile);
    bool readSpecifiedRecord(char *datafile);
    bool writeSpecifiedRecord(char *datafile);
};
```

Comment: Though this question is answered, it's still far too localised a question to be a useful part of the Stack Overflow Q&A repository. Your [minimal testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would have shown that you'd narrowed the problem down to attempting to read into `char townName[] = ""`, with a question title like "Why can't I read into `char townName[] = ""`? VTC for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char townName[] = "";
```

This is an array of size 1. You cannot read anything into it. Please drop the use of char arrays when using C++ and use `std::string`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Switching to string from char[] fixed the problem. :)